# Not able to upload a file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to upload a file on my server.

This is what I have tried:

```html
<input (change)="uploadImage($event.target)" hidden accept="image/*" #uploadProfileImage type="file">
```

```js
uploadImage(event) {
  const profileImage = event.files.item(0);
  this.profileService.postFile(profileImage).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    // do something, if upload success
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

postFile(fileToUpload: File): Observable<string> {
  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('fileKey', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
  console.log(fileToUpload);
  return this.httpClient.post<string>('/api//profile/profile-picture', formData);
}
```

But I get the error

> Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0

[image]

As you see in the image, I get the response of the server (*"I have received the request!"*) but it still throws an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `/api//profile/profile-picture`? `double slash` after api.

Comment: @random thanks, I have removed the slash but I still get the same error.

Comment: I just added an answer with my upload function for mutiple uploads: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59691405/1997073

Comment: @Reza - Are you using express as a `backend`. Is it running on `4200` port? You can separately check your backend api i:e if `http://localhost:4200/api/profile/profile-picture` is making call or not to your backend.

Comment: @random no, I'm not using express and the port is `80`.

Comment: @Reza - But the request is sent from `4200` port.

Comment: @random yes, it's from 4200 to 80. The call itself works. I have updated my question.

Comment: If you are running your app with `angular cli` then you have a dev server on 4200 port and you have to set an absolute url (like http://localhost:port/api/profile/picture) for your requests.

Comment: @epsilon I don' think that the URL is the problem. I have other methods that return e.g. `return this.httpClient.post<string>('/api/profile/update', data);`. They all work and I don't get any error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem:

The point is, I get this error since the response of backend is a string. If the response is either JSON or an integer, then the error disappears.